# Как посмотреть отличия только заданных папок?

Tags: git, git-diff

В хранилище большого проекта есть две ветки. Нужно посмотреть различие только определенных папок. Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- pathname1 pathname2 pathnameN
```

, где `branch1` - название первой ветки, `branch2` - название второй ветки, `pathnameX` - директории которые нужно сравнить

если добавить флаг `--name-only`, то будут выводится только названия файлов в которых есть изменения.

Comment: Добавь про --name-only. Мне кажется, полезная вещь.

Comment: @MaLS обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

$ git gui

---

-> Browse branch files ... или Browse ...(master) files

---

-> в директории можно выбрать файл и посмотреть историю

---

$ git log -p ... -- путь

---

смотрите в
[ru git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)  детали...